# Clear selection in MultiComboBox

Tags: sapui5

I want use MultiComboBox in a dialog to do a multi selection from a set of item.
I'm starting from this example: https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.m.sample.MultiComboBox/preview

My problem is that I don't know how delete selected keys of the previous selection when I open for the second time the dialog...

I have tried:

- .clearSelection()
- .getSelectedItems()=[]
- .getSelectedKeys()=[]
- .removeAllItems()
- .removeAllSelectedItems()
- .setSelectedItems([])
- setSelectedKeys([])

but the old selection remains

Comment: Worked for me with clearSelection. Are you loading the data from some model by any chance. Can you past some UI code so that we can get the context of the Dialog/Combobox

Comment: `oMultiComboBox.setSelectedKeys(null);` should work.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My solution is `destroy` the dialog fragment and recreate it every time:

```
if (myDialog !== undefined)
            myDialog .destroy();
myDialog  = sap.ui.xmlfragment("view.fragment.myDialog", this);
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code works if you want to clear the previously selected items when user opens select options popup:

```js
var oMulti = new sap.m.MultiComboBox({
  id: "multi",
  items: [
    new sap.ui.core.Item({text: "item 1", key:"item1"}),
    new sap.ui.core.Item({text: "item 2", key:"item2"}),
    new sap.ui.core.Item({text: "item 3", key:"item3"}),
    new sap.ui.core.Item({text: "item 4", key:"item4"}),
    new sap.ui.core.Item({text: "item 5", key:"item5"}),
  ]
});
oMulti.onAfterRenderingPicker = function(){
  if (sap.m.MultiComboBox.prototype.onAfterRenderingPicker) {
      sap.m.MultiComboBox.prototype.onAfterRenderingPicker.apply(this);
  }
  oMulti.clearSelection();  
};
```

Here is a working [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/lenesijofa/2/edit?html,output).

If someone can suggest cleaner or easier solution, I'd gladly learn it too.